# Value error when extracting data from Eurostat with Python

Tags: python

I am trying to access database with *eurostat* package in python from Eurostat.

```
import eurostat
StartPeriod = '2012'
EndPeriod = '2017'
filter_pars = {'FREQ': ['M'], 'PRODUCT': ['220410'], 'FLOW': ['2'],'INDICATORS': ['QUANTITY_IN_100KG'],'PARTNER': ['EU28_EXTRA'],'REPORTER': ['FR']}
data = eurostat.get_sdmx_data_df('DS-645593', StartPeriod, EndPeriod, filter_pars, flags = False, verbose=True)
```

It works for annual data, however when I try the same with monthly data(which I know is there) it gives me a value error.

```
header = list(s.key._fields).__add__([int(o.dim) for o in s.obs()]) # only from the last data row

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2012-01'
```

to see what's inside the database I suggest running this code:

```
dims = eurostat.get_sdmx_dims('DS-645593')

product = eurostat.get_sdmx_dic('DS-645593', 'PRODUCT')
flow = eurostat.get_sdmx_dic('DS-645593', 'FLOW')
freq = eurostat.get_sdmx_dic('DS-645593', 'FREQ')
indicators = eurostat.get_sdmx_dic('DS-645593', 'INDICATORS')
partner = eurostat.get_sdmx_dic('DS-645593', 'PARTNER')
reporter = eurostat.get_sdmx_dic('DS-645593', 'REPORTER')
```

I am guessing that my variables are of wrong type, but then again I am not really sure which one here is causing the problem. I would appreciate any insights.

Comment: In `[int(o.dim) for o in s.obs()]` you are trying to convert "2012-01" to int which raises the ValueError. There seems to be a month column that contains the month of observation. To see what you get back, you might just try to remove the cast to int from the generator expression (i.e. `[o.dim for o in s.obs()]`).

Comment: I would gladly do that, but tbh I don't really know how. These are the only lines of code I have. Is that somewhere inside the package?

Comment: You could just download the eurostat.py from the [project's bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/noemicazzaniga/eurostat/src/master/eurostat/eurostat.py) and import the respective functions you want to use (after altering the statements that break).

Answer (score 0):

The latest release of the package seems to have solved this problem (see https://pypi.org/project/eurostat/).